# Can I safely desynth raw materials from previous floors?

Tags: sequence

So far, it looks as if all the recipes you gain on one floor of the tower consist only of materials obtained from that floor.

Once I have cleared a floor and crafted all its recipes, can I desynth all the left-over materials or do they come in handy later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you *can* desynth most leftover materials after you've gone through all of the floor's recipes.

The exceptions are Crystals, which might be obtained before you have a recipe that involves them. Different Crystals can be synthed into a Half Prism and a Prism Half, which, together with an item dropped by the final boss, can be synthed into Iridium.

Doing so unlocks a bonus floor of the tower (floor "???").